# IE8 CSS hacks only work on local machine not server

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using an if conditional along with a stylesheet to address issues relating to IE8:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/iehacks.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#menuBar {
    margin-top: 2.65em;
}

#editing {
    margin-top: -3.30em;
    margin-left: 38em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.selectionTable th, .selectionTable td {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 3em 0 0em;
}

.selectionTable2 th, .selectionTable2 td {
    padding: 1em 4.3em 0 0em;
}

.selectionTableScrum th, .selectionTableScrum td {
    height: 3em;
}

#ieShiftField {
    margin-left: 1.50em;
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

#search {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

The issue I am encountering is that when I test the code and run the application via my local development server it looks fine:
[image]

When I publish the site to the server the css hacks don't appear to be working:

[image]

Shouldn't the browser be getting the same responses? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that CSS is published and loading correctly?

Comment: Do you have any comment stripping in effect on your server?

Comment: I am having trouble verifying that the css is loading correctly in IE8 because of it's limited tools but the source code looks correct and the same on the local and the server version.

Comment: F12 to open dev tools, verify that you're not in compatibility mode. IE typically uses compatibility mode for intranets including localhost.

Comment: Does the page on the server have this link resolved: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link href="/css/iehacks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

Comment: I am using a real version of IE8 zzzzBov not IE8 developer mode in IE10.

Comment: You sure you are looking at the latest CSS? try CTRL+R.